# Change label format for training

Tags: keras, lstm

Normally, if you train with keras, model.fit expects the train data to have a shape of (samples, timesteps, input) and a label of (samples, outputs). Is there a way to change the matching label to (samples*timesteps, output) or (samples, timesteps, input). So one sample matches len(sample)*label and not only one label?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can have whatever shape you want as the output layer. For instance auto-encoders will have the same output shape as input shape.

A toy example:

```
sequence_length = 20
n_features = 4
def make_model():
  inp = Input(shape=(sequence_length, n_features,))
  encoder = LSTM(16, return_sequences=True)(inp)
  vector = LSTM(32)(encoder)
  decoder_in = RepeatVector(sequence_length)(vector)
  decoder = LSTM(16, return_sequences=True)(decoder_in)
  out = Dense(4)(decoder)
  model = Model(inp, out)
  model.compile('adam', 'mse')
  return model

model = make_model()
model.summary()
```

In this case the `vector` layer has shape (32,) (i.e. there is a dimensionality reduction compared to the input) and the output layer has the same dimensions as the input.